# laravel update data mass assigned plus ch

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my update, a function I need change field the file before update mass assigned data.

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $path = "test";
    $post->file = $path;

    $post->update($request->except('slug'));
    $post->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just overwrite `fill()` method in your `Post` model.

```
public function fill(array $attributes, $path = false) {
    if ($path) {
        $attributes['path'] = $path;
    }

    return parent::fill($attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
$request['file']=$path;
```